# How to add class in nested element when click angular 7

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular7

When i click on button it contains `show` class and after another click `show` removes, that i was done but now my question is when i click on button `<div class="dropdown-menu">` contains `show` class and again click remove `show` class

I don't want to add `bootstrap.js, jquery.js and pooper.js` in my angular project, i don't want another directive for click or change class.

**app.component.ts**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
  appDropdown>Action</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**dropdown.directive.ts**

```
import {Directive, HostBinding, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
    @HostBinding('class.show') toggle = false;

    @HostListener('click') dropdownToggle() {
        this.toggle = !this.toggle;
        console.log('clicked');
    }
}
```

Comment: when you click Action button you want to append new class to dropdown menu?

Comment: yes but using directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use exportAs property on the Directive decorator

**directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]',
  exportAs:'appDropdown'
})
```

Then create a template variable and assign the appDropdown instance to the variable and append class using ngClass

**component.html**

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
  appDropdown #ref="appDropdown">Action</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" [ngClass]="{'show':ref.toggle}"  >
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksaqam

Comment: thanks for give me stackblitz, can you explain what you do ? please add explanation in your answer !!

Comment: I have export the directive and create local template variable #ref and assigned the directive #ref="appDropDown" Create local variable can access dropdown instance. using that i can access toggle  property and assigned to ngClass

Comment: what is different between #ref="appDropDown" and #appDropDown ?

Comment: #ref is local template variable which you can assign the directive to get access to the directive. whereas #dropDown mean it will give ref to the current element.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, in your code i dont know `ref.toggle` what is toggle ? because i deleted toggle from directive.ts file and program works fine ? why ? link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgxz9b?file=src/app/dropdown.directive.ts

Comment: Toggle is a property which you have defined inside directive

Comment: so if i remove @hostbinding toggle line, code not works exactly but it works why ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185935/discussion-between-nisharg-shah-and-chellappan).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to skip the directive and use ngClass:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" [class.show]="show" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" (click)="show=!show">Action</button>
```

Comment: any way to using directive ? because in my project there are too many dropdowns and if i add that it create too much duplication

Comment: You can add as much properties (like show above) as dropdowns. You don't even need to declare them in the class, html will manage them. The directive can be added, but it involves DOM manipulation.

Comment: It's so much easier to do it this way and it's Angular's way. The directive is like jquery translation and doesn't sound Angular way of doing it